# combined regex parse

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to catch the value of some HTML tag.
that could look like this:

```
value='3242312-3245-3245,234:3245:324,asdf asdf,asdf asd'>
```

or like this:

```
value=358 >
```

and maybe this:

```
value=83 selected='selected'>
```

I tried:

```
Pattern.compile("value=[[\'(.+)\'][(0-9)\\s]]")
```

but with no success...

any idea what pattern should I use?

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML parser to parse HTML? That's what they're made for.

Comment: what are the possbile values of the value attribute ?

Comment: Define "no success". Are you doing any other parsing? If so, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/438992.

Comment: @Dave this one the first answer I remember when I read this question:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression should work:

```
(?<field>\w+)=(('(?<value>[^']*)')|(?<value>\S+))
```

You can test [here](http://regexpal.com/) using the same expression w/o group names (since the tool doesn't support them):

```
(\w+)=(('([^']*)')|(\S+))
```